# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version X to Y when running an app

Tags: applications, system-error, sqlite

I have problem with TitaniumBackup. I had it installed on my Android tablet which is rooted and using Android 4.4.2. It was working fine, but I had to do factory reset and after that, if I try to launch TitaniumBackup, I get 'Unfortunately, Titanium Backup has stopped'.

This is the logcat with the lines that contain references to TitaniumBackup.

```
Line 111: E/AndroidRuntime(26306): Process: com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup, PID: 26306
Line 112: E/AndroidRuntime(26306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 7 to 6
Line 131: E/AndroidRuntime(26306):        at com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup.MainActivity.onCreate(Source)
```

The error mentions

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 7 to 6

How to mitigate this issue?

Comment: `Can't downgrade database from version 7 to 6`: looks like the Titanium Backup you used before the factory reset is newer than the current one. Have you updated it?

Comment: No, i didn't update it.

Comment: Looks more that you downgraded your TitaniumBackup version. You have to use the same or newer version of TitaniumBackup you used for creating the backup.

Comment: I didn't downgraded but this shouldn't matter anyway. After factory reset everything is deleted, right? It should not be any traces of previous Titanium Backup versions.

Comment: You didn't mention the Android OS version, but on Android Marshmallow or later, app data can be backed up and automatically restored after doing factory reset/reinstall.

Comment: It's android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: **Can't downgrade database from version 7 to 6**

This is caused when an app tries to downgrade an SQLite database from newer version, but failed since the code handle that is not implemented. (For more technical explanation: [Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1 even after fresh install and re-run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24053786/2821954)).

This can also happen on Android Marshmallow (Android 6.x) or later when the data is backed up and restored after doing factory reset, leaving the data with newer version, but the app in older version.

What the user can do:

1. If the user wants to use the existing database: they have to find and use the version of the app that is using the current (7)/newer (>7) SQLite database version. Usually this means the user *needs to update the app* to the previous app's version (before the factory reset) or newer one (latest from the Play Store/developer's website).
2. If the user doesn't care about the existing database: depending on the database location, they can remove the database by e.g. deleting the file manually (probably need root access), cleaning the app data, etc. and let the app recreate a *new* database with older SQLite database version (**big potential of data loss** from the previous database).

Comment: Where is this database located?

Comment: I was able to manually downgrade the database version of an IceCatMobile database via `sqlite3`. Root is required.